# Use jobParameters to Initialize a Property to Use in a Spring Init Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I want to initialize an attribute in my reader (path to a file) whose value will be passed into the jobParameters by executing my job using `CommandLineJobRunner` which takes as a parameter the path to the file.

Here is the configuration of my bean:

```
<bean id = "reader" class = "com.xyz.reporting.myReader" scope = "step" init-method = "init">
   <property name = "resource" value = "#{jobExecutionContext ['input.fileName']}" />
</ bean>
```

Here is the command:

```
java -cp "target / dependency-jars / *: target / my-project.jar" org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner src / main / resources / job.xml interceptorJob input.filename = "filePath"
```

In my reader I want to open the file in the init method (defined in the bean configuration)

```
 public final class MyReader implements ItemReader<Message>
    {
     ...
     /**
     * input filename
     */
     private String resource;

     public void setResource(String resource_p)
      {
        resource = resource_p;
      }

      public void init () throws Exception
      {

        File file = new File (resource);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (file));
      }
    ...
    }
```

Would it be a good practice to do that? Will the resource attribute be initialized when the init method is called, ie the jobParameters will already be initialized?

Before going further will this code will be testable with Junit?

Comment: Use `#{jobParameters}`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

**Would it be a good practice to inject the path to the file -** Yes.  You don't need to use the `init` method to do the injection though.  You can have Spring inject it via the `@Value` annotation like below:

```
@Value("#{jobParameters['input.fileName']}")
private Resource resource;
```

**Will the resource attribute be initialized when the init method is called, ie the jobParameters will already be initialized? -** Assuming you use the method I described above you wouldn't need to use an init method (Spring handles all it for you).

**Before going further will this code will be testable with Junit? -** Yes, all of this is testable.  We have unit tests that demonstrate that within the project on Github (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch).